# Django social auth return json on successful or failed login

Tags: django, json, facebook, django-socialauth

I am quite new to django and I am writing an application where I want to separate the client ant the server-side as much as possible so that multiple clients can access my server-side functionality.

Right now I am using Django social auth with Facebook login. Instead of redirecting to another page when login successes or fails I want to return json with success or fail. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it possible. You might want to take a look at [REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) or [Django Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/)

Comment: As it is right now, you cannot return such data from DSA, the only solution at the moment, could be to wrap the complete function from DSA with another one that checks the return value from the original and returns JSON by checking the redirect URLs (in case of error or OK status).

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem? I also want to return json instead of redirect the user

Comment: I ended up doint what @omab said, this was more than 2 years ago, so maybe there is a better solution for it now?